# Unusual behavior of set equality in python

Tags: python

When I am running this line of code, I could not understand why both `lists` are equal but `sets` created from the same list are not

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, fieldnames):
        self.name = fieldnames[0]
        self.alias = frozenset(fieldnames)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Field):
            return False
        return len(self.alias & other.alias) >= 1

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{field_name: %s}" % self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Field: (%s: %r)" %(self.name, self.alias)

In [185]: field_list1 = [["Field 1"], ["Field 2"], ["Field 3"]]

In [186]: field_list2 = [["Field 1"], ["Field 21", "Field 2"], ["Field 3"]]

In [187]: field1 = [Field(f) for f in field_list1]

In [188]: field2 = [Field(f) for f in field_list2]

In [189]: field1 == field2
Out[189]: True

In [190]: set(field1) == set(field2)
Out[190]: False
```

According to python docs on set two sets are equal if each element of first set is in the second set and vice versa. As per that definition both set should be equal, but I am not sure why they are not.

> Therefore I wanted to know reason behind such behavior?

Comment: What are `d` and `e`? Did you mean `field_list1` and `field_list2`?

Comment: `field1` has `"Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3"` in it as the `name` properties of the `Field` objects. But field2 has `"Field 1", "Field 21", "Field 3"`. Those are not the same.

Comment: If you want to find transitive groups of Fields that are aliases of each other, you could consider using a [union-find or disjoint set algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct d meant field_list1, e meant field_list2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different comparisons going on here.

When comparing two lists, each element in the first list is compared with the equivalent element in the other list via `==`, which calls your `eq` method. Although your code for that method is very odd (why not just `len(self.alias) == len(other.alias)`?), it results in a True or False depending on the relative sizes of the alias attributes.

However sets work completely differently. There comparison is done by hash, not by equality; and you have defined your `__hash__` method to return different result based on the name, not the alias.

Answer (score 1):

`field1 == field2` performs item-wise comparison using `==` oprerator (by calling `__eq__`).

`set(field1) == set(field2)` checks if all elements are in both sets. Elements in sets are identified by their hashes. You calculate the hash from the names. Some  elements in the list have different names, so they are different set elements.

```
print(field1[1].name)  # 'Field 2'
print(field2[1].name)  # 'Field 21'
```

In summary, list comparison is based on `__eq__` but set comparison is based on `__hash__`. They are based on totally different calculations in the `Field` class, so you get different results.